# How to join command output lines into by separating then with \n character

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have below data which is just fetching the data which is 80 or more than `80%`

```
# ssh udcl804 aggr show -root false | awk '/^udc/{if($4 >= 80) print $0}'
udc8003_ssd02 127.2TB 10.09TB  92% online     179 udc8003          raid_dp,
udc8004_ssd02 127.2TB 18.95TB  85% online     149 udc8004          raid_dp,
udc8013_sata02 160.1TB 16.30TB 90% online     325 udc8013          raid_dp,
udc8014_sata02 160.1TB 22.18TB 86% online     328 udc8014          raid_dp,
udc8015_sata02 160.1TB 18.32TB 89% online     316 udc8015          raid_dp,
udc8016_sata02 160.1TB 23.97TB 85% online     316 udc8016          raid_dp,
udc8017_ssd02 131.6TB 25.79TB  80% online     101 udc8017          raid_dp,
udc8018_ssd02 131.6TB 22.30TB  83% online      83 udc8018          raid_dp,
udc8020_sata02 199.4TB 17.46TB 91% online     117 udc8020          raid_dp,
udc8026_ssd02 130.4TB 21.32TB  84% online     104 udc8026          raid_dp,
udc8030_ssd02 130.9TB 18.48TB  86% online     129 udc8030          raid_dp,
```

I am just looking if we could all the lines into one by separating them by newline character `\n` and the closing it within double quotes as this is required for the destination format.

```
"udc8003_ssd02 127.2TB 10.09TB  92% online     179 udc8003          raid_dp,\nudc8004_ssd02 127.2TB 18.95TB  85% online     149 udc8004          raid_dp,\nudc8013_sata02 160.1TB 16.30TB 90% online     325 udc8013          raid_dp,\nudc8014_sata02 160.1TB 22.18TB 86% online     328 udc8014          raid_dp,\nudc8015_sata02 160.1TB 18.32TB 89% online     316 udc8015          raid_dp,\nudc8016_sata02 160.1TB 23.97TB 85% online     316 udc8016          raid_dp,\nudc8017_ssd02 131.6TB 25.79TB  80% online     101 udc8017          raid_dp,\nudc8018_ssd02 131.6TB 22.30TB  83% online      83 udc8018          raid_dp,\nudc8020_sata02 199.4TB 17.46TB 91% online     117 udc8020          raid_dp,\udc8026_ssd02 130.4TB 21.32TB  84% online     104 udc8026          raid_dp,\nudc8030_ssd02 130.9TB 18.48TB  86% online     129 udc8030         raid_dp,"
```

This is just in continuation of [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933689/how-to-add-the-double-quote-at-the-very-first-and-at-the-end-of-last-line/66933803?noredirect=1#comment118315317_66933803).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf()` instead of `print`, as it doesn't automatically add a newline. Then you can put a literal `\n` in the output. I've put this in a variable so I don't put it before the first line, only all subsequent lines.

Use `BEGIN` and `END` blocks to print quotes around it.

```
ssh udcl804 aggr show -root false | awk 'BEGIN {printf "\""; prefix=""}
    /^udc/{if($4 >= 80) printf("%s%s", prefix, $0); prefix="\\n"}
    END {printf "\""}'
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, i have forgot to mention as this entire output has to be within double quotes as well, that i have shown in my desired output, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've updated the answer to wrap the quotes, and also not put `\n` after the last line.